# How do I use double quotes inside FOR in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have the following example code:

```
 @for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('%SystemRoot%\system32\reg query "some key" /v "some value"') DO (
    echo "inside for"
)
```

I'd like to use double quotes like this: `"%SystemRoot%\system32\reg"` in case there was a space character in that path, but FOR doesn't like it. How can I resolve this? Thank you!

Comment: Just as additional information, you could replace `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg` with `%__AppDir__%Reg.exe`. I have added the file extension, because if you are having to provide the full path to the System32 directory there is likely an issue with `%Path%` which could bring about doubt regarding `%PATHEXT%`.

Comment: `@for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('^""%SystemRoot%\system32\reg.exe" query "some key" /v "some value"^"') do @echo "inside for"`

Comment: Thank you MC ND, Compo, aschipfl for your time. This has helped me.